# Google Apps Script сохранить письмо в черновиках

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-apps-script

Необходимо из Google Docs создать письмо и не отправлять его, а сохранить в черновиках без отправки. Подскажите как это возможно реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

### Обновлено

Создать черновик средствами Apps Script

```js
// The code below creates a draft email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
GmailApp.createDraft(
  "mike@example.com",
  "current time",
  "The time is: " + now.toString()
);
```

[Class GmailApp  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers | createDraft](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String))

### Предыдущий ответ

Это хороший вопрос, уже потому, что средствами Google Apps Script решить его нельзя, кстати, можно поставить звездочку [Ability to create draft message by GmailApp](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=985). Но, косвенный способ существует, который по количеству вызовов будет не больше стандартных. Он описан по ссылке из предыдущего предложения.

Положим, что нам надо сделать вот что

```
function createDraft() {
  //Запрос разрешений
  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount(); // needed for auth scope
  
  //Тело письма
  var body = {
    'subject': 'TEST',
    'to': 'test@test.com',
    'content':'testing Draft'
  };
  
  //Fetch
  var response = draft.setBody(body).createDraft();
  
  //Делаем что-то с ответом с сервера
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());  
}
```

Расширим возможности Google Apps Script

```
(function() {
  //global
  var root = this;
  var draft = function(){};
  var body = {
    'Subject': '',
    'To': '',
    'Content': '',
    'raw': ''
  };
  
  //setBody
  draft.setBody = function(obj){
    body.Subject = obj.hasOwnProperty('subject') ? '' + obj.subject : '';
    body.To = obj.hasOwnProperty('to') ? '' + obj.to : '';
    body.Content = obj.hasOwnProperty('content') ? '' + obj.content : '';
    body.raw = Utilities.base64Encode([
      'Subject: ' +  body.Subject,
      'To: ' + body.To,
      'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=112233445566778899',
      body.Content,
      '--112233445566778899--'
    ].join('\n'));
    return this;
  }
  
  //createDraft
  draft.createDraft = function(){
    if(!body.raw) return;
    return gapi_post('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts', {'raw': body.raw});
  }
  
  //private
  function gapi_post(api, message){
    var params = {
      method: 'post',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      payload: JSON.stringify({
        'message': message
      })
    };    
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api, params);
    return resp;
  }
  
  //export
  root.draft = draft;
}.call(this));
```

Описание [Gmail REST API Users.drafts: create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create) гласит, что будет создан черновик с ярлыком `DRAFT`. Что успешно и происходит.

Этот скрипт будет работать от имени того, кто авторизировал скрипт, если вам надо его распространять для конечного пользователя, то необходимо спрашивать у пользователя его `'Authorization': 'Bearer '` + [результат работы библиотеки](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2).

Так же необходимо включить [advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) для текущего скрипта. Сами сервисы включать нет нужны, а необходимо перейти в консоль и включить GMAIL API `https://console.developers.google.com/project/{YOUR_PRIJECT_ID}/apiui/apiview/gmail/overview`

[Пример скрипта](https://script.google.com/d/1UyKOZ7CHbOFIMGO7tGnKH03GnmH4v1r1I0r_hX3JeAclQP2DLJoaARlE/edit?usp=sharing)